# ¿Cómo se traduce "Compliance Hotline"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

Una "compliance hotline" es una línea telefónica (o recurso similar) que algunas empresas tienen para que, por ejemplo, un trabajador pueda dar un "chivatazo" de forma anónima sobre algo ilegal, dudoso o contra las normas de la empresa.

Por ejemplo, si ves que uno de tus colegas intenta sobornar a un posible cliente para que acepte un acuerdo o ves que uno de tus jefes humilla a uno de tus colegas por su condición sexual puedes usar este recurso y el departamento correspondiente de la empresa investigará el asunto.

`Hotline` puede ser traducido según el contexto como "línea de asistencia", "línea de soporte" o "línea informativa".

`Compliance` puede traducirse como "cumplimiento de normas", "responsabilidad" o "conformidad".

Sin embargo, al poner las dos cosas juntas lo mejor que me sale es "línea (de asistencia o informativa) de conformidad legal".

¿Hay alguna manera de expresarlo en la que con menos palabras se exprese mejor?

Answer (score 4):

Nunca me ha tocado traducir la frase, pero a partir de la explicación he encontrado muchos sitios en Internet que utilizan "línea directa de cumplimiento". Es bastante literal. Para mi gusto, le faltaría el concepto de "seguimiento" o "comprobación" de que se están cumpliendo las normas, y - a pesar de que la Internet no me avala - usaría con más beneplácito una frase como "línea directa de verificación/control de cumplimiento".

También podríamos decir algo así: "línea directa de detección de incumplimientos/irregularidades/no conformidades".

Comment: The suggestion of _linea directa_ seems to me a better translation than the three that @Diego offered in his question. The characteristic of a hotline is that a fully competent person answers you straightaway.

Comment: @mdewey I just clicked on the "Compliance hotline" link of my company's website to see what's there and you reach another page where you have more info: several toll-free numbers you can call (depending on your country), an email address, a third-party website and a fax number. The "hotline" is not just a _phone_ line anymore. I also want to think that is a quick and easy way of _directly_ reaching someone who will address the problem, but I doubt that is the case in many of those. Some are just like an "anonymous tip". Still, I agree that "lines direct" convey what we expect a hotline to be.